# Laravel belongsTo return null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i have two model

**Word Model:**

```
class Word extends Model
{
 public function pos()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Pos::class);
    }
}
```

and **PoS Model**:

```
class Pos extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'pos';
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

now in controller i want to get `word` and `pos` relationship but `pos` relationship return null when i specify the columns

**Controller**

```
$word = Word::with(['pos'])->whereId( $vocabulary->word_id)->get(['id', 'word', 'surface', 'gloss', 'example','sound_url'])->first();
```

*note when i use query without specify the columns work perfectly*

```
   $word = Word::with(['pos'])->whereId( $vocabulary->word_id)->first();
```

i have been tried use `addselect` , `with closure` but same result

Comment: Make sure you're also getting the column that the relationship is based on.

Comment: Does `Word::whereId( $vocabulary->word_id)->get(['id', 'word', 'surface', 'gloss', 'example','sound_url'])->first();` work?

Comment: @apokryfos yes of course

Comment: @apokryfos with another relationship such `has many` work   perfectly but with `belongto` not working and return null

Comment: @MortaddaJafar try this `get(['id', 'word', 'surface', 'gloss', 'example','sound_url', 'pos.*'])`

Comment: @Sandeesh i tested not working

Comment: Try running a raw select, see if it helps `->selectRaw("id, word, surface, gloss, example, sound_url, pos.*")->first()`

Comment: Does  `$word = Word::with(['pos'])->whereId( $vocabulary->word_id)->get(['id', 'word', 'surface', 'gloss', 'example','sound_url',"pos_id"])->first();` work?

Comment: yes it's work thanks  @apokryfos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try to add `pos_id` to that columns array.

Comment: please read my question ..its work without Specify the columns

Comment: yes, I understood your question... when you specify columns you don't specify column responsible for relationship so maybe thats why It doesnt work. So add 'pos_id' to ['id', 'word', 'surface', 'gloss', 'example','sound_url'] this array.