# Laravel - Eloquent with select not returning values

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I'm having the following problem, I'm using `scope` in Laravel and I have the following relationship:

**Enquiry**

```
pickup_address

dropoff_address

Notes
```

This is referenced in the model:

```
public function pickup_address() {
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Address', 'pickup_address', 'id');
}
```

I want to return the enquiry, as well as `postcode` which is stored in the `Address` table. I just want this column from this table and I have done the following:

```
return $query->with(['pickup_address' => function ($query) {
    $query->select('postcode');
}])->get();
```

This gives the following (json):

```
{
   "id":1,
   "pickup_address":null 
   "notes":"hello world",  
   "created_at":"2017-06-08 09:56:52",
   "updated_at":"2017-06-08 09:56:52"
}
```

This is not giving the postcode and just gives the `pickup_address` as null. However, removing the `$query->select('postcode')` gives:

```
{
 "id":1,
  "pickup_address": {
     "id":140,
     "house_number":null,
     "address_1":"Address 1",
     "address_2":null,
     "postcode":"POSTCODE",
     "city":"CITY",
     "county":"C0UNTY",
     "created_at":"2017-06-08 09:56:23",  
     "updated_at":"2017-06 0}",
   "notes":"Hello world","
   "created_at":"2017-06-08 09:56:52",
   "updated_at":"2017-06-08 09:56:52"
}
```

However, I'm using `Vue` and using a table, so I just need the particular field to be returned that matches the column, rather than the entire object being returned.

Can anyone suggest a solution, please? I have followed some examples online and they suggest the `$query->select('postcode')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel belongsTo return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44183460/laravel-belongsto-return-null)

Comment: @apokryfos Not a duplicate since it's not returning null, only in certain circumstances

Comment: Read that question. The issue is that if you're doing a `select` you **have to include the foreign keys**

Comment: @apokryfos `$query->select('postcode', 'pickup_address');` gives me: `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'pickup_address' in 'field list' (SQL: select `postcode`, `pickup_address` from `addresses` where `addresses`.`id``

Comment: Probably not `pickup_address` but `id`

Comment: @apokryfos Cool that worked! Thanks :)! Is it possible to get it to return without an object, though? (Using JSON) I would like to combine the two

Comment: Laravel does have the `->toJson()` and `toArray` methods you can use on a result set

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146179/discussion-between-phorce-and-apokryfos).